# How to add user input objects to arrays in React using useState

Tags: reactjs

I tried to solve the problem of adding users and phone numbers entered from the keyboard into the Persons array but I didn't know where the problem was. Can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

```
const PersonForm = () => {
  let input = this.props.input;
  console.log();
  return (
    <form onSubmit={e => this.props.handleSubmit(e)}>
      <div>
        Name:
        <input
          name="name"
          type="text"
          value={input.name}
          onChange={e => this.props.handleChange(e)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        Number:
        <input
          name="number"
          type="text"
          value={input.number}
          onChange={e => this.props.handleChange(e)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    name: "",
    number: ""
  });

  const addPerson = input => {
    setPersons([...persons, { name: input.name, number: input.number }]);
  };

  const handleChange = e => {
    setInput({
      ...input,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addPerson(input);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Phonebook</h1>
      <h3>Add a new</h3>
      <PersonForm
        input={input}
        addPerson={addPerson}
        handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
        handleChange={handleChange}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Maybe I misunderstood useState. Looking forward to receiving your help. Sorry to bother.
Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-b7-controlled-form-phonebook-qz1pr

Comment: Functional components don't have `this`, for one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.props...` only when inside class components and not functions. So you get them as parameters and access them. And what I did is that when you actually add a person, the inputs should be cleared.

Here's the full code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const PersonForm = ({ handleSubmit, handleChange, input }) => {
  const { name, number } = input;
  console.log();
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        Name:
        <input
          name="name"
          type="text"
          value={name}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        Number:
        <input
          name="number"
          type="text"
          value={number}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    name: "",
    number: ""
  });

  const addPerson = input => {
    setPersons([...persons, { name: input.name, number: input.number }]);
    setInput({ name: "", number: "" });
  };

  const handleChange = e => {
    setInput({
      ...input,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addPerson(input);
  };

  console.log(persons);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Phonebook</h1>
      <h3>Add a new</h3>
      <PersonForm
        input={input}
        addPerson={addPerson}
        handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
        handleChange={handleChange}
      />
    </>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your improved code.

```
const PersonForm = props => {
  console.log();
  return (
    <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        Name:
        <input
          name="name"
          type="text"
          value={props.input.name}
          onChange={props.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        Number:
        <input
          name="number"
          type="text"
          value={props.input.number}
          onChange={props.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </div>
      <hr />
      {props.persons.map(p => (
        <p key={p.name}>
          {p.name}---{p.number}
        </p>
      ))}
    </form>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    name: "",
    number: ""
  });

  const addPerson = input => {
    setPersons([...persons, { name: input.name, number: input.number }]);
  };

  const handleChange = e => {
    setInput({
      ...input,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addPerson(input);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Phonebook</h1>
      <h3>Add a new</h3>
      <PersonForm
        input={input}
        persons={persons}
        handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
        handleChange={handleChange}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-b7-controlled-form-phonebook-04q4l)

Comment: @Thien if answer is helpful for you please accept/vote for this.

Comment: Sorry, I just joined the forum so this is not clear. Can you just help me?

Comment: @Thien yeah, tell